# concatenate exe mode commands in command assignment

Tags: vim

I've a few files I want to apply folds to in a specific format incorporating two fixed elements and the contents of the `"` register. I was using a macro to do it but lately the files aren't in a consistent enough format.

I have 4 registers set by a function

```
@v='========= BEGIN'
@b='========== END'
@n=' =========={{{'
@m=' ==========}}}'
```

I find where the fold has to go yank the descriptor and then set the following and paste at the begiing and end

```
let @z=@v.@".@n
let @x=@b.@".@m
```

I tried every combination I could think of to concatenate the register assignment into a single map such as  variations of

```
nnoremap <leader>X :'let @z=@v.@".@n | let @x=@b.@".@m'
```

Couldn't get it to work so added it to the function and mapped the function call to the X key.

Is there a way to chain command assignments in a key mapping? The functin works but the concept would be useful eslewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<bar>` or `\|`.

```
nnoremap <leader>X :'let @z=@v.@".@n <bar> let @x=@b.@".@m'
nnoremap <leader>X :'let @z=@v.@".@n \| let @x=@b.@".@m'
```

Take a look at `:help map_bar`

Comment: I didn't actually test the concatenation but the quotes look suspicious.

Comment: Thanks FDinoff that works a treat and yes the quotes should be removed.